# What is the reason why mongo can return one document muliple times in aggregation query by multiple fields?

Tags: database, mongodb

My agggregation query returns one document multiple times in response.

I'tried to rebuild indexes at collection, but it didn't help me.

What reason of it can be?

Comment: Could be anything.  Your question provides no details.  If you are seeking assistance I would recommend you provide example documents you are attempting to query, and provide the query itself for evaluation.

Comment: Please share query with collection ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course , the reason was because of wrong aggregation request )).